# How to group api response in android

Tags: java, android, api

This is the json response I am recieving:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "sports": "Cricket",
        "name": "Suraj" 
        "year": "2017",
        "rank": "1",
        "age": "25",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "sports": "Cricket",
        "name": "Rajeev"
        "year": "2017",
        "rank": "2",
        "age": "24",
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "sports": "Cricket",
        "name": "Kiran"
        "year": "2015",
        "rank": "1",
        "age": "25",
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "sports": "Badminton"
        "name": "Shekhar"
        "year": "2017",
        "rank": "1",
        "age": "22",
    },
    {
       "id": "5",
        "sports": "Badminton"
        "year": "2017",
        "name": "Karan"
        "rank": "2",
        "age": "22",
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "sports": "Cricket",
        "name": "Ali"
        "year": "2017",
        "rank": "3",
        "age": "26",
    }
]
```

I need to represent this information in a table after grouping it according to the sports type, then again sub group it into years, as in the picture I have attached. But I have no idea how to do that. Can someone help me with this ?

[image]

I have created this model class:

public class prev_data {

```
      private String id;
    
        private String sports;
    
        private String name;
    
        private String year;
    
        private String rank;
    
        private String age;
    
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getSports() {
            return sports;
        }
    
        public void setSports(String sports) {
            this.sports = sports;
        }
....
```

}

And this is how I am calling the api through retrofit:

```
List<prev_data> prevList;

 Call<List<prev_data>> call3 = apiInterface.getPrev_data();
        call3.enqueue(new Callback<List<prev_data>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<prev_data>> call3, Response<List<prev_data>> response3) {
               prevList= response3.body();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<prev_data>> call3, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated and acknowledged.