# Do I need to make a recyclerview inside a recyclerview for this?

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, tableview

This question is in link with my previously asked question here:
[How to group api response in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64252837/13677712)

I didn't get any efficient way of doing this, so I have changed my api to this:

```
{
    "Cricket": {
        "2017": {
            "id": "1",
            "Name": "Karan",
            "age": "25"
        },
        "2015": {
            "id": "2",
            "Name": "Suman",
            "age": "24"
        }
    },
    "Badminton": {
        "2016": {
            "id": "1",
            "Name": "Kiran",
            "age": "25"
        },
        "2015": {
            "id": "2",
            "Name": "Shikhar",
            "age": "26"
        }
    }
}
```

Will this help, if yes, can someone guide me how?

Comment: yes you can follow this example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-nested-recyclerview-in-android/

Comment: You could also use a library like https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView to do the nested recyclerviews for you.